# Swift Value of type 'Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalInfo' has no member 'renewalDate

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I downloaded Xcode 15 beta 2 to develop an app after iOS 16.5 didn't support Xcode 14. I'm ready to submit my app to the App Store but I have to use Xcode 14.3.1 as it appears you can't upload using beta's. When I build in Xcode 14 I get the following error regarding StoreKit: `Value of type 'Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalInfo' has no member 'renewalDate` - I've checked the Documentation and it is supported from iOS 15+ (my target is iOS 16+).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/subscriptioninfo/renewalinfo/4193529-renewaldate

How can I solve this error as I need the renewal info from storeKit?

Here's my method:

````
func mapped(from product: Product, renewal: Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalInfo?) {
        id = product.id
        level = setLevel(for: product.id)
        if let renewalInfo = renewal {
            renewalDate  = renewalInfo.renewalDate // It says this doesn't exist??
            billingRetry = renewalInfo.isInBillingRetry
        } else {
            Task {
                guard let transaction = await product.latestTransaction else { return }
                renewalDate = transaction.signedDate
            }
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: You could use status.transaction.unsafePayloadValue.expirationDate. I will try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like bug in Apple documentation (2023), when you access the definition in Xcode of `Product.SubscriptionInfo.RenewalInfo` then there is no `renewalDate`  property.

*update 13.10.2023:* confirmed from Apple support it's only for XCode 15 - see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738833?login=true&r_s_legacy=true.

When you do print of renewalInfo object, then you can see it there.

```swift
if let item = try await products[sku]?.subscription?.status.first {
 if let verificationResult = item.renewalInfo {
  let renewalInfo = try verificationResult.payloadValue
   print(renewalInfo)
```

output:

```
{
  "autoRenewProductId" : "product_B",
  "autoRenewStatus" : 0,
  "deviceVerification" : "MrWi...",
  "deviceVerificationNonce" : "3d...",
  "environment" : "Sandbox",
  "originalTransactionId" : "2000000425656293",
  "productId" : "product_A",
  "recentSubscriptionStartDate" : 1696256551000,
  "renewalDate" : 1696260151000,
  "signedDate" : 1696257225930
}
```

Same for `debugDescription` and `jsonRepresentation`.

It's ugly, definitely don't think it's the best solution, but we parsed it back from `jsonRepresentation`.

Context: we are using XCode 14.2